# Original file and output file do not match while Reading UIImage into buffer and writing back to UIImage in iOS

Tags: ios, uiimage

Using the below code I get `UIImage` from `ALAsset`

```
  ALAssetRepresentation * assetRepresentation = [asset defaultRepresentation]; // Big Picture
                imageRef = [assetRepresentation fullResolutionImage];

                if (imageRef)
                {
                    UIImage* image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage: imageRef];
                }
```

Now I create a buffer out of this `UIImage` using below code:

```
  + (unsigned char *) convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8:(UIImage *) image {

    CGImageRef imageRef = image.CGImage;

    // Create a bitmap context to draw the uiimage into
    CGContextRef context = [self newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:imageRef];

    if(!context) {
        return NULL;
    }

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(imageRef);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(imageRef);

    CGRect rect = CGRectMake(0, 0, width, height);

    // Draw image into the context to get the raw image data
    CGContextDrawImage(context, rect, imageRef);

    // Get a pointer to the data
    unsigned char *bitmapData = (unsigned char *)CGBitmapContextGetData(context);

    // Copy the data and release the memory (return memory allocated with new)
    size_t bytesPerRow = CGBitmapContextGetBytesPerRow(context);
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    unsigned char *newBitmap = NULL;

    if(bitmapData) {
        newBitmap = (unsigned char *)malloc(sizeof(unsigned char) * bytesPerRow * height);

        if(newBitmap) { // Copy the data
            for(int i = 0; i < bufferLength; ++i) {
                newBitmap[i] = bitmapData[i];
            }
        }

        free(bitmapData);

    } else {
        NSLog(@"Error getting bitmap pixel data\n");
    }

    CGContextRelease(context);

    return newBitmap;
}
```

Now, I convert the buffer back into `UIImage` using below code:

```
 + (UIImage *) convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage:(unsigned char *) buffer withWidth:(int) width withHeight:(int) height
{
    size_t bufferLength = width * height * 4;
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer, bufferLength, NULL);
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bytesPerRow = 4 * width;

    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if(colorSpaceRef == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        return nil;
    }
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault | kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    CGImageRef iref = CGImageCreate(width,
                                    height,
                                    bitsPerComponent,
                                    bitsPerPixel,
                                    bytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpaceRef,
                                    bitmapInfo,
                                    provider,        // data provider
                                    NULL,                // decode
                                    YES,                        // should interpolate
                                    renderingIntent);

    uint32_t* pixels = (uint32_t*)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(pixels == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error: Memory not allocated for bitmap");
        CGDataProviderRelease(provider);
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
        CGImageRelease(iref);
        return nil;
    }

    CGContextRef context = CGBitmapContextCreate(pixels,
                                                 width,
                                                 height,
                                                 bitsPerComponent,
                                                 bytesPerRow,
                                                 colorSpaceRef,
                                                 bitmapInfo);

    if(context == NULL) {
        NSLog(@"Error context not created");
        free(pixels);
    }

    UIImage *image = nil;

    if(context)
    {

        CGContextDrawImage(context, CGRectMake(0.0f, 0.0f, width, height), iref);

        CGImageRef imageRef = CGBitmapContextCreateImage(context);

        // Support both iPad 3.2 and iPhone 4 Retina displays with the correct scale
        if([UIImage respondsToSelector:@selector(imageWithCGImage:scale:orientation:)]) {
            float scale = [[UIScreen mainScreen] scale];
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef scale:scale orientation:UIImageOrientationUp];
        } else {
            image = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
        }

        CGImageRelease(imageRef);
        CGContextRelease(context);
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpaceRef);
    CGImageRelease(iref);
    CGDataProviderRelease(provider);

    if(pixels) {
        free(pixels);
    }
    return image;
}

+ (CGContextRef) newBitmapRGBA8ContextFromImage:(CGImageRef) image {
    CGContextRef context = NULL;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpace;
    uint32_t *bitmapData;

    size_t bitsPerPixel = 32;
    size_t bitsPerComponent = 8;
    size_t bytesPerPixel = bitsPerPixel / bitsPerComponent;

    size_t width = CGImageGetWidth(image);
    size_t height = CGImageGetHeight(image);

    size_t bytesPerRow = width * bytesPerPixel;
    size_t bufferLength = bytesPerRow * height;

    colorSpace = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();

    if(!colorSpace) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating color space RGB\n");
        return NULL;
    }

    // Allocate memory for image data
    bitmapData = (uint32_t *)malloc(bufferLength);

    if(!bitmapData) {
        NSLog(@"Error allocating memory for bitmap\n");
        CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);
        return NULL;
    }

    //Create bitmap context

    context = CGBitmapContextCreate(bitmapData,
                                    width,
                                    height,
                                    bitsPerComponent,
                                    bytesPerRow,
                                    colorSpace,
                                    kCGImageAlphaPremultipliedLast);    // RGBA
    if(!context) {
        free(bitmapData);
        NSLog(@"Bitmap context not created");
    }

    CGColorSpaceRelease(colorSpace);

    return context; 
}
```

Then.. save to Photo Album:

```
 +(void) saveImageToPhotoAlbum : (UIImage*) image
{
    if( image != nil)
    {
        NSData* imageData =  UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);     // get png representation
        UIImage* pngImage = [UIImage imageWithData:imageData];

        UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(pngImage, self, nil, nil);
    }
    else
    {
        NSLog(@"Couldn't save to Photo Album due to invalid image..");
    }
 }
```

My calls are like below

```
void *imageData = [self convertUIImageToBitmapRGBA8 : image];



UIImage* uiImage = [self convertBitmapRGBA8ToUIImage : imageData withWidth:width withHeight: height];

[self saveImageToPhotoAlbum:uiImage];
```

When I do this.. the file size changes and both files do not seem to be same..

e,g; if Original File size is 33KB, after going through this process, it changes 332KB.. what is wrong here?

Answer (score 1):

Yes, loading an image into a `UIImage` and then calling `UIImagePNGRepresentation` (or even `UIImageJPEGRepresentation`) may result in a file size change. Guessing from the file sizes, it looks like the original image was a JPEG. PNG files are generally larger than JPEG files that are compressed, often even if they have only a modest degree of compression. If you want a file of comparable size, try `UIImageJPEGRepresentation` with various quality settings (e.g. `compressionQuality` of 0.99 or 0.9 or 0.8).

As an aside, just the exercise of loading the image into a `UIImage` may cause a bit of a change from the original asset (if nothing else, stripping meta data, possibly changing color space, etc.).

Comment: My input is also PNG file.. is there any way, I can convert this to raw .BMP file ? Any sample code would be really helpful..

Comment: @codersnet iOS only offers functions to create JPEG and PNG representations. I'm sure there are third party libraries to create image data of different formats, but I'd stick with one of these two file formats, personally. PNG is lossless, but the compression is less impressive. JPEG offers greater compression opportunities, but is lossy.